# populate taxonomy from another taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have 2 exposed filters in a search page "drop down lists", I want to populate the second exposed filer "taxonomy" from the first one:

example 
vehicle {car, plane, ship}
and the second should be {BMW, Honda, etc} 
only if vehicle car is selected in the first drop down list.
thanks

Comment: Is that other taxonomy or a Level ?

Comment: A level or a child for a taxonomy term.

Comment: In question you mentioned populate **taxonomy from _another_ taxonomy**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for this, I used [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)
and it worked like a charm.